# Facebook Login Mobile error: redirect_uri is not owned by the application

Tags: facebook

My facebook login on my website works perfectly in normal browsers on my laptop.  When I try to login on my cell phone (Android 2.2) I am getting the following error:
redirect_uri is not owned by the application

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On https://developers.facebook.com/ under your app/settings verify that the url you have matches the redirect url you are using.

Is the mobile instance running from a different url?

Please include your code if this doesn't help.